# PopupWindow on CustomDialog

Tags: android, customdialog

I've a one CustomDialog(it is implemented in other package),like below

```
customDialog = new CustomizeDialog(this);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.student_register_form);
```

And in CustomDialog have a one button, when I click on that and PopUpWindow will display

```
countryPopupWindow = new ListViewPopupWindow(context, R.layout.grade_popup_layout, values, Ids, "country");
```

This is custructor,and implemented every thing,I got Popup window also but it is displaying on MainActivity,not On CustomDialog

Comment: But CustomDialog will be dismissed after click on button if you called customDialog.dismiss();

Comment: No sir,here CustomDialog is like that only,it'll close when I click cancel button,other wise not,and popupwindow is on behind CustomDialog

Comment: But you can't see one dialog into another dialog.

Comment: Can you tell me when and where your **CustomizeDialog** being called????

Comment: Isn't it ?,so what can I do ?

Comment: you have to show your pop up dialog after click on button but your customDialog will be dismissed

Comment: yah,in MainActivity,On register button,when I click on that,one customedialog( with R.layout.student_register),on that one button named as countries,when I click on that popupList will display

Comment: @PiyushGupta,one thing tell me,how I find the context of CustomDialog.

Comment: customDialog = new CustomizeDialog(MainActivity.this);

Comment: Frankly,we not able to give the Context,as for my doubt,I wandered there and there,finally I used by the Inflater.